# Dynamic SQL Server Query loop through schema find primary key duplicate

Tags: sql, dynamic-sql, azure-synapse

**EDIT:** There seems to be some confusion around the create table statements. These are there solely as a demonstration of what tables *might come in to our synapse instance, not as actual code that will run. The important part of the question is contained in the latter half.

---

I am trying to create a stored procedure that loops through every table in a supplied schema and outputs the count of duplicate primary key rows for each table. Assume that the data is being supplied from elsewhere and the primary keys are not being enforced. For example I may have three tables in the stack schema:

```
CREATE TABLE stack.table1(
          id int,
          name NVARCHAR(MAX),
          color NVARCHAR(20)
         PRIMARY KEY (id))
 INSERT INTO stack.table1 VALUES(1,'item1','yellow')
                                (2,'item2','blue')
                                (2,'item2','blue')

CREATE TABLE stack.table2(
          id int,
          name NVARCHAR(MAX),
          size NVARCHAR(1)
         PRIMARY KEY (id,size))
INSERT INTO stack.table2 VALUES(1,'item1','L')
                                (2,'item2','M')
                                (3,'item2','S')
CREATE TABLE stack.table3(
          id int,
          name NVARCHAR(MAX),
          weight NVARCHAR(20)
         PRIMARY KEY (id))
INSERT INTO stack.table1 VALUES(1,'item1','200lb')
                                (2,'item2','150lb')
                                (3,'item2','125lb')
```

I want to supply a variable to a stored procedure to indicate the schema (in this case 'stack') and have that procedure spit out a table with the names of the tables in the schema and the counts of duplicate primary key rows. So in this example a stored procedure called 'loopcheck' would look like this:

## Query:

```
EXEC loopcheck @schema = 'stack'
```

## Output:

| table | duplicate_count |
| --- | --- |
| table1 | 1 |
| table2 | 0 |
| table3 | 0 |

I am using an Azure Synapse instance so there are several functions that are not available (such as FOR XML PATH and others.) Since each table may have a single column primary key or a composite primary key I need to join to the system provided tables to get primary key info. My general idea was like so:

```
CREATE procedure loopcheck @schema= NVARCHAR(MAX)
AS 
BEGIN

create table #primarykey(
SCHEMA_NAME nvarchar(400),
TABLE_NAME nvarchar(500),
COLUMN_NAME nvarchar(500)
)

insert into #primarykey

select l.TABLE_SCHEMA,
l.TABLE_NAME,
l.COLUMN_NAME
from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.CONSTRAINT_COLUMN_USAGE l
inner join INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS t on l.constraint_Name = t.CONSTRAINT_NAME
where
l.table_schema = @schema

CREATE TABLE #groupBy2(
    TABLE_NAME nvarchar(50),
    groupby nvarchar(200)
    )

INSERT INTO #groupBy2

SELECT TABLE_NAME, STRING_AGG(CONVERT(NVARCHAR(max), COLUMN_NAME), ',') as groupby
FROM #primarykey
GROUP BY TABLE_NAME

DECLARE @currentTable NVARCHAR(MAX)=''

DECLARE @currentGroup NVARCHAR(MAX)=''

create table #work4(
    TABLE_NAME nvarchar(400),
    COUNT int)

DECLARE @final NVARCHAR(MAX)=

'INSERT INTO #work4
SELECT '+@currentTable+', COUNT(*) FROM '+@currentTable+'GROUP BY'+@currentGroup

WHILE (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM #groupby2)>0
BEGIN
    SET @currentTable =(SELECT TOP 1 TABLE_NAME FROM #groupby2 ORDER BY TABLE_NAME)
    SET @currentGroup =(SELECT TOP 1 groupby FROM #groupby2 ORDER BY TABLE_NAME)
    exec @final
    DELETE #groupby2 where TABLE_NAME =@currentTable
END
END
```

This code gives me an error:

> Incorrect syntax near 'SELECT'

but doesn't give me the actual line it has the error on.

Comment: Is the error happening when trying to exec @final? Or in the static SQL? To debug the dynamic SQL change you exec to print and test the SQL produced.

Comment: Something doesn't add up here. You can't have duplicate primary key values. That is the point of a primary key. And "primary keys are not being enforced" makes absolutely no sense at all. Maybe what you are referring to aren't actually primary keys? I can't understand your question here at all.

Comment: Could you show an example (CREATE TABLE statement) of a table you know has duplicates?  As @SeanLange mentions, maybe you don't actually have a primary key defined or you aren't referring the primary key itself, but some other column(s) which have no corresponding constraint.  The insert for table1 should fail, unless you somehow have disabled the constraint, which would be an odd thing to do.

Comment: See the following fiddle, using your database (SQL Server): `https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=1f40cdb8367834a6d816e79d5173de62`

Comment: I agree with @SeanLange - your question doesn't make sense.  In fact, your script won't insert the 'duplicate' row for table stack.table1 because it does define the PK on the ID column.  My guess is that you should have defined a composite key (unique constraint at a minimum) using all of the columns that make that row unique.  If that is the case - dynamically creating any code is not possible because you don't know which columns are needed to uniquely identify each row.

Comment: I used the create table statement as an example to illustrate a table that has duplicate keys and what the output should be, not to replicate what is actually happening. The data is created by a third party and given to us to transform. We do not have control over how the data is created. The primary keys are not being enforced by Synapse even though they should.

Comment: @SeanLange, - From this article you can infer that PK and Unique "constraints" are really just query optimiser hints i.e. they do not do any data enforcement: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/synapse-analytics/sql-data-warehouse/sql-data-warehouse-table-constraints

Comment: @corgiraptor - please use correct tags in your question. Your question should NOT include SQL Server tag, instead it should have azure-Synapse tag.

Comment: @Alex - at the time of my comments it was not clear to me they were using azure-synapse as the tags were inconsistent. Just proves once again how important tagging correctly is. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Your primary issue was syntax errors: parameter declaration should not have `=` between name and type name, and missing spaces in the dynamic SQL.

Also

- A schema name (or any object) can be up to `nvarchar(128)`, you can use the alias `sysname`
- You don't need to do any loops or use temp tables, you can build one big dynamic statement to execute

```sql
CREATE procedure loopcheck
  @schema sysname
AS 

DECLARE @sql nvarchar(max) = (
    SELECT STRING_AGG(CAST('
SELECT
  TableName = ' + QUOTENAME(t.name, '''') + ',
  IndexName = ' + QUOTENAME(i.name, '''') + ',
  Duplicates = COUNT(*)
FROM (
    SELECT 1 n
    FROM ' + QUOTENAME(s.name) + '.' + QUOTENAME(t.name) + ' t
    GROUP BY ' + cols.agg + '
    HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
) t
'
        AS nvarchar(max)), 'UNION ALL')

    FROM sys.tables t
    JOIN sys.schemas s ON s.schema_id = t.schema_id
          AND s.name = @schema
    JOIN sys.indexes i ON i.object_id = t.object_id
          AND i.is_unique = 1

    CROSS APPLY (
        SELECT STRING_AGG('t.' + QUOTENAME(c.name), ', ')
        FROM sys.index_columns ic
        JOIN sys.columns c ON c.column_id = ic.column_id AND c.object_id = t.object_id
        WHERE ic.index_id = i.index_id
          AND ic.object_id = i.object_id
          AND ic.is_included_column = 0
    ) cols(agg)
);

PRINT @sql; -- for testing
EXEC sp_executesql @sql;
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=8ec8eb2f5936d82e0df427bcc0d70c2a)

I feel like there might be a slightly more efficient method using `GROUPING SETS` in cases where there are multiple unique indexes/constraints on a single table, but I'll leave that to you.

Comment: This has several syntax errors as well. Have you run this query?

Comment: Sorry copy/paste mixup, should be fixed now